# How to use a many2one field to display two fields together in OpenERP (odoo)?

Tags: odoo

I have a `column` where I currently have a `many2one` field which brings the `Name` of an employee from another class. The thing is that I need more than just the name, I would like to bring `Name + last name`.

I understand I have to use a `function field` but I don't understand how to tell the new function where to look for the values.

If anyone can point me documentation or a similar example I can follow I will really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 'name_get' method to achieve this.

```
def name_get(self,cr,uid,ids,context=None):
    result = {}
    for record in self.browse(cr,uid,ids,context=context):
        result[record.id] = record.name + " " + record.lastname

    return result.items()
```

Following is just an example:

There is a model 'sale.order', in that there is a model 'res.partner' as many2one. So let's say you want to display 'First Name' and 'Last Name' of that partner in that many2one field.

So for that you have to write your code in the model 'res.partner', not in the 'sale.order' model.

Here is the code in 'res.partner' model.

```
class res_partner_extention(osv.osv):

_inherit = 'res.partner'

def name_get(self,cr,uid,ids,context=None):
    result = {}
    for partner in self.browse(cr,uid,ids,context=context):
        result[partner.id] = partner.name + " " + partner.lastname

    return result.items()
```

So now, in the 'sale.order' when you will try to look into the partner field, when you click on that many2one partner field it will show you 'First Name' as well 'Last Name'. So you don't need to anything 'sale.order' model nor you have to define any field as 'field.function'.

Comment: Thanks a lot Hardik, `record` should be the name of the model where the `name` and `lastname` is stored?

Comment: Yes, it is the model which used in the many2one field. You will have to write this suggested method in the that model / class.

Comment: HI, could you share how to call the field. I am using this `'Name':fields.function(name_get, type = 'many2one', method = True, string = 'Name')`, but it is giving me this error `Field sim.xp.namelastname with unknown comodel_name None `. I am not sure I am fully understanding how `name_get` knows where to grab the fields I need from another class. Thanks again

Comment: thanks a lot! I was writing my code in the wrong model! thanks a lot for your help, I really appreciate it.